# Regular expressions matching text between two strings

Tags: python, python-re, lookbehind

Kind of a beginner to coding and working on a personal project to learn more. I converted some personal statements to text and trying to do a lookbehind and lookahead at the same time. I have a chunk of text with the following format:

```
> dec 15 dec 16 transaction info#1 ab74537812345678951843053$16.94
\ndec 16 dec 17 transaction info#2 cd74500123456789617492488$56.50
```

I'm trying to do a findall that selects all matches after the first date and before the long string of 20+ digits. For example for the the first line it would match:

> transaction info #1 ab

This is the current expression I have at the moment, which matches what I am looking for but it also matches bunch of blanks: `(?<=.{14})(?:.*?)(?=\d{23,})`. I guess I can remove the blanks that appear in the findall list through some additional coding, but not sure that is the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I tend to match the whole line, and use groups to select what I actually want.
Here's the example input you provided on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/YiG8dM/3)

Using the example you provided, I came up with the following expression to serve that purpose:

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]{3}\s*[0-9]{1,2}\s*){2})(.*)(?:[0-9]{23}\$.*)$
```

This is using the flags global (`g`) and multiline (`m`) so that it returns all matches and captures multiple lines.

This utilizes non-capturing groups to isolate the portion of the line that you actually want to read. Additionally, by using the "start of string" and "end of string" tokens (`^ ... $`), any line that does not match this whole pattern will simply not match.

Based on your example, this pattern matches both lines, with the first capturing group in each line as follows:

```
transaction info#1 ab
transaction info#2 cd
```